# Local variable 'list' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I made a simple script that converts any input text into a "code" and can also translate it back. It only works one word at a time.

I want to make the script adds each new code to a list that is printed every time. For example, the first time you translate something, `"HELLO"` becomes `"lohleci"`. The second time, I want it not only to show `"world"` = `"ldwropx"`, but also state below everything translated so far.

I'm new to Python and have looked through forums for people with similar problems. The way I tried doing it (a segment was removed and put into a separate script), I get an error saying "local variable 'list' referenced before assignment." This is the code producing the error:

```
list = "none"
def list():
    word = raw_input("")
    if list == "none":
        list = word + " "
        print list
        list()
    else:
        new_list = list + word + " "
        list = new_list
        print list
        list()
list()
```

Comment: You should not use the name `list`, either as a variable or function. Also your function is recursively calling itself, is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah, kindof. As I said I pulled this from a much larger script where after every word it translated it went back to the part where you input the next word. My problem is I want to be able to eventually input something specific like /print and have it show me all the things I translated total in this session. So this isn't actually how it'll go, it's just the section I pulled out for testing where yes, it should repeat itself. Thank you for looking at it. :) I tried this however with nothing under the name list and it still gave me this error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You should use loop, instead of recursion, except you really know you need recursion. Care of `stack overflow`(not this site!). Your question is not clear, if you can give any expected output would be helpful.

Comment: As Leo Law already said, you shouldn't use the name `list`, as that's the name of a Python function. Use something like `the_list` for a variable, or `make_list()` for a function.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I'll try all of these suggestions.

Comment: Also Leo, I'm just taking the kahn academy course for python and I barely just finished how to make recursions. I don't know how to make a loop yet. When I figure out how, I plan on fixing all of the code to be loops but at the moment I just got asked by a friend to make a simple script like this for him :)

Comment: The absolute first thing to do when you get an error message you don't recognize is to search the web for the exact text of the message. You did the right thing, though, posting your code as text rather than an image. Images are hard to read and unsearchable. Please always use text to post code on this site.

Comment: I've never looked at the Khan Academy course on Python, but if it's anything like other Khan Academy courses, it's probably pretty good. After you finish it, though, I **highly** recommend going through the free book [Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/). That should take your programming skills to the next level.

Comment: As an aside, when you ran this program, you got a stack trace the pointed to the line that failed. Its important to include that stack trace in your question here so that we don't have dig around so much to see the problem. If you go to the doctor, you point to where it hurts. Same rule applies here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has several problems, all of which are fixable with a bit more knowledge.

1. Don't use the name `list` for your own variables or functions. It's the name of a built-in Python function, and if you use that name for your own functions you won't be able to call the built-in function. (At least, not without resorting to advanced tricks which you shouldn't be trying to learn yet.)
2. You're also re-using the same name (`list`) for two different things, a variable *and* a function. Don't do that; give them different, meaningful names which reflect what they are. E.g., `wordlist` for the variable that contains a list of words, and `get_words()` for your function.
3. Instead of using a variable named `list` where you accumulate a set of strings, but which isn't *actually* a Python list, why not use a real Python list? They're designed for exactly what you want to do.

You use Python lists like this:

```
wordlist = []
# To add words at the end of the list:
wordlist.append("hello")
# To print the list in format ["word", "word 2", "word 3"]:
print wordlist
# To put a single space between each item of the list, then print it:
print " ".join(wordlist)
# To put a comma-and-space between each item of the list, then print it:
print ", ".join(wordlist)
```

Don't worry too much about the `join()` function, and why the separator (the string that goes between the list items) comes before the `join()`, just yet. That gets into classes, instances, and methods, which you'll learn later. For now, focus on using lists properly.

Also, if you use lists properly, you'll have no need for that `if list == "none"` check you're doing, because you can `append()` to an empty list just as well as to a list with contents. So your code would become:

**Example A**

```
wordlist = []

def translate_this(word):
    # Define this however you like
    return word

def get_words():
    word = raw_input("")
    translated_word = translate_this(word)
    wordlist.append(translated_word)
    print " ".join(wordlist)
    # Or: print ", ".join(wordlist)
    get_words()

get_words()
```

Now there's one more change I'd suggest making. Instead of calling your function at the end every time, use a `while` loop. The condition of the `while` loop can be anything you like; in particular, if you make the condition to be the Python value `True`, then the loop will never exit and keep on looping forever, like so:

**Example B**

```
wordlist = []

def translate_this(word):
    # Define this however you like
    return word

def get_words():
    while True:
        word = raw_input("")
        translated_word = translate_this(word)
        wordlist.append(translated_word)
        print " ".join(wordlist)
        # Or: print ", ".join(wordlist)

get_words()
```

Finally, if you want to get out of a loop (any loop, not just an infinite loop) early, you can use the `break` statement:

**Example C**

```
wordlist = []

def translate_this(word):
    # Define this however you like
    return word

def get_words():
    while True:
        word = raw_input("")
        if word == "quit":
            break
        translated_word = translate_this(word)
        wordlist.append(translated_word)
        print " ".join(wordlist)
        # Or: print ", ".join(wordlist)

get_words()
```

That should solve most of your problems so far. If you have any questions about how any of this code works, let me know.

Comment: I gotta go for now, But I'll get back to you on this! Looks a bit complicated but hey I'm trying to learn! :D Thank you so much for your help! I'd up vote / favorite etc but I'm brand new and I don't have enough reputation or something like that? .-. that's a little odd

Comment: @JamesHartman - Stack Overflow is designed so that new users can't do much besides ask questions or answer other people's questions at first. In particular, new users aren't allowed to upvote answers, to avoid people creating a bunch of fake accounts and upvoting their own answers. But once you get up to 15 reputation points, you'll be able to upvote an answer.

Comment: @JamesHartman - In the meantime, you can always *accept* an answer if you found it useful. Accepting an answer means "Of all the answers I received, this one was the best" -- and if someone later gives a better answer, you can accept that one instead. Accept the answer by clicking on the outline of a checkmark under its score.

Comment: @JamesHartman - If you're feeling intimidated by my answer, go through it one example at a time. Start by studying example A until you start to understand it. Then once you've got a handle on example A, move on to example B. Once you understand example B, then move on to example C. That should help you digest the new knowledge in slightly more bite-sized pieces.

Comment: Great answer. There is one more issue though. It's the use of global variables. By default python does not let you write to global variables without first declaring the variable to be global in your scope (the function's scope in this case). If not declared as global then assignment will create a local that shadows the global. The actual error in this case is that python thinks `list` is local variable, but that the if statement reads its value before it has been given a value.

Comment: @Dunes - Good point, I forgot to mention that one. On reflection, I think I'll hold off on explaining the global/local(/builtin) distinction until the OP has a bit more experience, as I don't want to overwhelm him with too much new material to learn all at once. Presumably the Khan Academy course he's going through will explain it at some point; if it doesn't, I *know* the Think Python book I recommended will explain it.

Comment: Good point. There is a you've covered. Maybe an example that doesn't use globals might be a good idea though. Get OP out of a bad practice before it becomes ingrained.